# Removing lines in a text file based on the beginning characters

Tags: ruby

I have an email message which looks like this:

```
Hey how are you?

On Saturday sender@example.com wrote:
> something
> On Friday sender@example.com wrote:
>> previous thing
```

How would I remove the lines that start with `>` as well as lines that include `email@example.com wrote`

Should I even keep the "someone wrote" part as that could remove legitimate lines, maybe only removing that line if it's the last line.

I'm trying this out:

```
message_filtered = message_txt.to_s.split("\n").each do |m|
  if m[0] != ">" then
    return m
  end
end

puts message_filtered
```

I could push `m` to an array and then join that array with `\n` but i'm trying a shorter way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
message_filtered = message_txt.lines.reject { |line|
  line[0] == '>' || line =~ YOUR_EMAIL_REGEXP
}.join('\n')
```

To remove lines that start with `>` you can use:

```
message_filtered = message_txt.gsub(/(^>.+)/, '') # should work but not tested
```

Comment: It should be `message_filtered = message_txt.gsub /(^>.+)/, ''`, in regex `$` indicates end of line.

Answer (score 2):

my proposition:

```
message_filtered = '';
message_txt.to_s.lines {|line| message_filtered << line unless line[0] == '>' }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
> str = "Hey how are you?\nOn Saturday sender@example.com wrote:\n> something\n> On Friday sender@example.com wrote:\n>> previous thing"
> str.split("\n").reject{|msg| msg =~ /^>/ || msg =~ /@example.com/}.join("\n")
 => "Hey how are you?"
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.gsub` with a simple regex can do this:

```
text = <<EOT
Hey how are you?

On Saturday sender@example.com wrote:
> something
> On Friday sender@example.com wrote:
>> previous thing
EOT

puts text.gsub(/(?:^>|On \w+ sender@example.com wrote:).+\n/m, '')

# => "Hey how are you?\n\n"
```

Comment: sender@example.com needs to be a simple email regex.

Comment: You get to figure that part out. I'm just showing that `gsub` will handle this nicely.

Comment: cheers, I was trying out a regex from regular-expressions.info but it stopped registering as a regex after so many characters. but really i only need to check for `*@* wrote:`